# what code to add to search.php

Tags: pagination, search, code

what line of code can i add to my search page in order to display the results up to 3-5 pages per "search

Comment: Can you clarify/expound upon your question. I don't really understand what you're asking/trying to accomplish.

Comment: Jim, you've asked 5 questions over the last year without accepting one answer. Good acceptance rate == more answers and people willing to participate in your discussion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to show more results on your search results page? this is defined by the posts per page setting in the admin panel, but can be modified in the search.php template by adding this before the loop:

```
<?php
$myquery = "&posts_per_page=50"; // set to number of results you want per page
$myquery = $query_string.$myquery;
query_posts($myquery);
?>
```